# BATCH: grep equivalent

Tags: mysql, batch-file, grep

I need some help what ith the equivalent code for **grep -v Wildcard** and **grep -o** in batch file.

This is my code in shell.

```
result=`mysqlshow --user=$dbUser --password=$dbPass sample | grep -v Wildcard | grep -o sample`
```

Comment: Please ask about your actual issue/what you are trying to do.  Why do you need an equivalent?  Equivalent to this in what (in what environment)? As it is, it is not clear how this should be answered.

Comment: Batch is exclusive to Windows. He needs the Windows equivalent of grep, which (based on the way he's using it) will be `findstr`.

Comment: Try to not use the old and outdated back tics, use parentheses like this: `result=$(mysqlshow ......)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch equivalent of grep (not including third party tools like [GnuWin32 grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)), will be `findstr`.

`grep -v` finds lines that don't match the pattern. The findstr version of this is `findstr /V`

`grep -o` shows only the part of the line that matches the pattern. Unfortunately, there's no equivalent of this, but you can run the command and then have a check along the lines of

```
if %errorlevel% equ 0 echo sample
```